# Правила константности для составных объектов C/C++

Tags: c++, c, const

Как принято определять константность в следующей ситуации?

У меня имеется интерфейс - несколько функций для работы с контейнером хэш-отображением. Хэш-отображение содержит пары `key-value`, ключи дублироваться не могут.

Есть функция `for_each()`, предназначенная для перебора всех пар. Эта функция не может менять `key` перебираемых узлов, но может менять `value`.

Сама функция выглядит так:

```
ptrdiff_t c_hash_map_for_each(const c_hash_map *const _hash_map,
                              void (*const _action_key)(const void *const _key),
                              void (*const _action_data)(void *const _data));
```

Меня мучает следующий логический вопрос: поскольку функция перебора всех пар не меняет структуру хэш-отображения, было бы логично считать, что она принимает указатель на константный контейнер.

Но...

`for_each()` может менять `value` узлов, поэтому можно считать, что `for_each()` изменяет, пускай и не структуру контейнера, но содержимое, а значит функция `c_hash_map_for_each()` должна выглядеть так:

```
ptrdiff_t c_hash_map_for_each(c_hash_map *const _hash_map,
                              void (*const _action_key)(const void *const _key),
                              void (*const _action_data)(void *const _data));
```

Как поступить правильнее?

Comment: если функция меняет объект, то, конечно, она не может быть const. Разве что можете добавить const для указателя, чтобы показать, что в функции он не будет изменен.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, я и сам больше склонялся к такому варианту.

Comment: кстати от того что все указатели делать константными пользы практически никакой, а читаемость страдает...

Answer (score 0):

### **Вам стоит объявить ваше поле как *mutable*.**

Если ваша функция не меняет "логическую" константность объекта, но по своим внутренним причинам может менять какое-то поле (в вашем случае value), то это поле следует объявить как **mutable**:

```
//...
mutable int value;
//...
```

Это ключевое слово указывает, что данное поле может меняться константными функциями вашего класса. Также его можно менять у константных экземпляров вашего класса, если, конечно, имеется доступ к вашему полю (если оно не является приватным, или если вы обращаетесь к нему из дружественной функции).

Однако, следует точно быть уверенным, что эта функция не меняет "логическую" константность объекта, это значит, например, что имея доступ через публичный интерфейс вы не сможете обнаружить разницу между объектом до применения вашей функции и после (хотя внутри и произошли изменения, но они скрыты от пользователя). Если ставить **mutable** где попало, вы фактически уничтожите преимущества const-методов.

Пример, где использование **mutable** оправдано. Пусть у вас есть класс, у которого есть метод, считающий некоторое число по сложному алгоритму, при этом сам класс не меняется, логично, чтобы этот метод был константным. Но вам не хочется каждый раз это число долго считать, поэтому вы хотите закэшировать его, так, чтобы оно считалось лишь при первом вызове, а при остальных вы будете просто возвращать уже подсчитанное значение. Переменная, в которую вы занесёте кэшированное значение будет объявлена как mutable int cachedVar; .

Ещё один часто встречающийся пример. В вашем классе при (константном) доступе на чтение нужно выполнять синхронизацию через мьютекс, доступ на чтение, то есть константный (ничего в классе не меняет), но мьютекс у используется как поле класса. Операция захвата и освобождения мьютекса не является константной, но захватывать/освобождать его необходимо в константной функции. В этом случае мьютекс следует объявить как **mutable** .

Ещё про mutable: [Про mutable у Алёны C++](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2005/10/mutable-constcast.html)

Comment: "константные функции" это лишь одна из отправных точек. Суть `mutable` в возможности изменение члена-данных константного **объекта**. А как это делается, через константную функцию-член класса или, например, дружественную функцию, принимающую так или иначе константный объект, или вовсе напрямую при наличии доступа, не так важно.

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение, не знал про это. Думал, что это только для методов класса работает. Значит можно просто объявить член как mutable, и тогда в любом месте, где возникает константный экземпляр этого класса, мы сможем поменять это поле, верно? Не имеет значения, является ли поле приватным или публичным, не имеет значения, экземпляр класса существует сам по себе, или получен как this в константной функции. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Ну, экземпляр должен быть. `mutable`-член ведь должен кому-то принадлежать. А так, разницы откуда менять - нет, если есть видимость этого члена вообще.

Comment: Я большую часть времени пишу на C)